# Zoom not working on Loading pickled matplotlib Figure

Tags: matplotlib, pickle

I want to store a matplotlib figure and load it later to use it interactively. To be more specific, I want to be able to use zoom in this figure. 
I am using pickle to dump the figure handle into a file.
I then load the figure later using pickle, but the zoom does not work after loading the file even though I can use zoom in the figure before pickling it.

Here's a sample script that illustrates my problem.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
import time

# Create Plot Data
x = np.arange(100)

# Create Figure, Axes and plot
fig1,axes1 = plt.subplots()
axes1.plot(x)

# Pickle plot
fileName = os.getcwd() + "/img"\
+ time.asctime(time.localtime()) + ".pickle"
with open(fileName,'wb') as pickle_file:
    pickle.dump(fig1,pickle_file)

plt.show() # ZOOM WORKS HERE
plt.close()

# Load pickled plot 
with open(fileName,'rb') as read_pickle:
    fig_handle = pickle.load(read_pickle)

plt.show() # ZOOM DOES NOT WORK HERE
```

[Zooming into the image before Pickle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYKYt.png)

[Non-Zoomable image after Pickle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcfDv.png)

Version:
Python 3.7.0
Matplotlib 3.0.0
Pickle 4.0

Is this a limitation with Pickling matplotlib figure? Or is there something I can do to load/dump the figure in a zoomable way?

Comment: This does work for me in matplotlib 2.2.3 as well as with matplotlib 3.0.1, both with TkAgg and Qt5Agg backend. Which versions/backends/OS are you using?

Comment: I am using OSx 10.13.6 (High Sierra). Matplotlib is version 3.0.0.
matplotlib.get_backend() -> MacOSX.
I will try changing my backends and check.

Comment: Changing the backend to 'TkAgg' fixed my problem. Thanks a lot! I will add this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @ImportanceOfBeingErnest pointed out I fixed the problem by changing my backends from MacOSX to TkAgg.

Here's what I did.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend() # Get the current backend
'MacOSX'
# Get Location where configuration file was loaded from.
matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
'/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc'
# Edit -> backend:TkAgg
matplotlib.get_backend()
'TkAgg'
```